# Ubuntu 12.04: user configuration sudden rollback

Tags: linux, ubuntu, restore

I am a newbie to Linux and after half of year working in Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) had encountered the following strange thing: one day I am doing manual restart of Linux PC and at next boot observing absence of some installed programs or configuration changes which I made in last X months. It looks like Linux did rollback to some old saved point:

1. profile file has a content without my changes done in this X
   months
2. installed programs (in this X months) are marked in Synaptic
   application as not installed
3. configuration settings, made in some programs (in this X months),
   vanished

Firstly I connected this phenomenon to Linux auto-update, and asked never to do any updates. But now this option is also turned back to be executed daily. What is it???
Does Linux have something like restore feature in Windows (I want to backup my software configuration at some point and then to have possibility restore it!) ?

### EDIT: SOLVED

At some point I have cleared that ALL my files modification dates are about 3 months ago!.. and suddenly I remembered that in that period did snapshot of my primary Linux HDD partition to another partition (on the same HDD). It seems after one of the soft reboots by some reason (why?) the Linux failed to mount its primary partition and found instead the second one - this snapshot - and booted from it. But how is it possible that Linux doesn't inform a user about such thing? Or at least may be it logged in some GRUB log-files? If yes - where can I find it?
After I did actual shutdown (not reboot) and then switched PC on – it booted normally!

Answer (score 0):

That's not supposed to happen. It would be one thing if apt automatically uninstalled software because of your /etc/apt/sources.list got corrupt or something, but for settings and files to "roll back" like that is very strange. There is no direct equivalent to Windows "system restore" that I know of, however package lists and profile settings can be backed up and then easily restored using package and profile lists.

But again, for a machine to 'go back in time' like that is odd indeed. However, I did  recently have exactly what you described happen to my Verizon Fios router, which is a Linux powered device. One day my entire router configuration 'rolled back' to the way I had it set it up a couple months before-- effectively destroying many hours of configuration time I had put into my network. The culprit? Probably verizon, as they like to log into their customers routers via telnet periodically and change security settings with no explanation or consent, and they did do just that according to the security logs.

So when I read this, I figured I'd tell you that it makes little sense, and that perhaps you should back up all of data, download (and VERIFY with GPG) another copy of Ubuntu and then reinstall it on your computer, from the ground up. At least that is what I would do, just to be safe. Although I suppose it is theoretically not *so* far fetched for a hard drive to time-capsule corrupt in this manner, it's very unlikely and makes me think that there is something fishy going on with your software. And if it is a mechanical error, than chances are it could happen again. Check the SMART status of your hard disc for errors as well, because if your disc somehow is responsible than it could very well happen again.

Comment: Check your /var/log/syslog files. Try doing something like : cat /var/log/syslog | grep dev/sd*  to see all the hard drive related messages.